# Fail in Building Apache Tez from Source

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-tez

I am setting up a cluster of nodes (CentOs 8) using Hadoop version 3.3.6. And I have tried to set up Apache Tez (version 0.9.2) for the execution engine of Hive (version 3.1.3) with Java 8. But after settin up hadoop version in pom.xml and hitting `mvn clean package -DskipTests=true -Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true`, it ends up being like this:

```
[INFO] 4 warnings
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/apache-tez-0.9.2-src/tez-dag/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/state/StateMachineTez.java:[28,8] org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPreviousState() in org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachine
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
[INFO] tez 0.9.2 .......................................... SUCCESS [  1.240 s]
[INFO] hadoop-shim ........................................ SUCCESS [  1.435 s]
[INFO] tez-api ............................................ SUCCESS [  5.870 s]
[INFO] tez-build-tools .................................... SUCCESS [  0.105 s]
[INFO] tez-common ......................................... SUCCESS [  0.560 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-internals .............................. SUCCESS [  0.871 s]
[INFO] tez-runtime-library ................................ SUCCESS [  2.554 s]
[INFO] tez-mapreduce ...................................... SUCCESS [  1.232 s]
[INFO] tez-examples ....................................... SUCCESS [  0.258 s]
[INFO] tez-dag ............................................ FAILURE [  2.530 s]
[INFO] tez-tests .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-ext-service-tests .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-ui ............................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-plugins ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-protobuf-history-plugin ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-yarn-timeline-history-with-acls ................ SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-history-parser ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-aux-services ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-tools .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-perf-analyzer .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-job-analyzer ................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-javadoc-tools .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-shim-impls .................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] hadoop-shim-2.7 .................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] tez-dist ........................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Tez 0.9.2 .......................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 17.025 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-07T19:24:55Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project tez-dag: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/apache-tez-0.9.2-src/tez-dag/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/state/StateMachineTez.java:[28,8] org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPreviousState() in org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachine
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project tez-dag: Compilation failure
/usr/local/hadoop/apache-tez-0.9.2-src/tez-dag/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/state/StateMachineTez.java:[28,8] org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPreviousState() in org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachine

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
/usr/local/hadoop/apache-tez-0.9.2-src/tez-dag/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/state/StateMachineTez.java:[28,8] org.apache.tez.state.StateMachineTez is not abstract and does not override abstract method getPreviousState() in org.apache.hadoop.yarn.state.StateMachine

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute (AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilerMojo.execute (CompilerMojo.java:129)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:954)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR]
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :tez-dag
```

I've downloaded an older version but it was totally in vain due to some errors like this:

```
[ERROR] /usr/local/hadoop/apache-tez-0.9.0-src/tez-mapreduce/src/main/java/org/apache/tez/mapreduce/client/NotRunningJob.java:[89,29] no suitable method found for 

newInstance(org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationId,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.ApplicationAttemptId,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,

<nulltype>,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.YarnApplicationState,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,int,int,org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.FinalApplicationStatus,

<nulltype>,java.lang.String,float,java.lang.String,<nulltype>)
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider building newer version (if possible) like [tez 10.1](https://github.com/apache/tez/releases/tag/rel%2Frelease-0.10.1)
and before building apply patches from [bigtop repository](https://github.com/apache/bigtop/tree/master/bigtop-packages/src/common/tez)

With this metod i succesfully build tez 10.1 on rocky8 (rhel compatible) and even created rpm for rhel8, although i was building against hadoop **3.3.4** and hive 3.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

After Hadoop YARN devs have fixed this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/YARN-11395 and backported it to a few previous release versions, Tez devs hit the same issue and has fixed it [here](https://github.com/apache/tez/commit/50380751b7e7e628aeb40a985b94aba98d2a88db).

As you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/commit/bf8ab83cd00fcbbc77e96b9ae41f4664ec646965#diff-27c70742f1ba654831b3269730d52c20bf5a2072d61db599ccff574470e0f03e), there is a new method in `StateMachine` interface which needs to be overridden in any class that implements it.

`StateMachineTez` also implements `StateMachine` interface. So, what you need to do is to override the new method in `StateMachineTez` class before building it;

```
  @Override
  public STATE getPreviousState() {
    return realStatemachine.getPreviousState();
  }
```